# Purchase commitment for e2-medium

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Planned to purchase a commitment for the e2-medium machine as per the pricing calculator. But in the purchase commitment page it has only e2 general and it is mentioned, it does not support shared core (e2-medium is shared core machine)

**Question** - Purchasing e2 general commitment will cover e2-medium machine as per the pricing calculator?

[image: Pricing calculator screenshot] [image: Purchase commitment screenshot]

Comment: Hi there. Contact GCP [Sales department](https://cloud.google.com/contact). Looks like the answer is **no** and that the calculator does not take onto consideration this shared vcpu restriction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a software development question as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 5):

I just spoke with GCP Billing Support regarding Committed Use Discounts for an e2-medium in australia-southeast1. CUD's are supported/allowed for E2 Shared-Core Machines!

For an e2-medium you would CUD for 1 cpu and 4gb of ram (2nd cpu is burstable).

As the doco doesnt say you can't do shared-core for E2 like it does for N1: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#commitment_types

The pricing calculator greys out committed years field when trying to use an f1-micro but not an e2-medium: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator

Comment: Where did you find the information that for e2-medium you'd purchase a CUD for 1 vcpu? It seems plausible, but I cannot find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think the GCP calculator is pretty poor. The E2-medium instances aren't currently eligible for CUD (since they're already about 30% discounted) and running on a shared core.

Comment: The e2 are not eligible for sustained use discounts.  They are available for CUD.